# How to show that a hamiltonian solution is finite?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the Hamiltonian system : $$\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \omega}H(z,\omega), \quad z(0)=a$$
$$\frac{d\omega}{dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}H(z,\omega), \quad \omega(0)=b$$
also
$$\left |\frac{\partial H}{\partial z}(z,\omega) \right|\leq c \sqrt{|\omega|^2+1} \quad :(1)$$

and $$\left |\frac{\partial H}{\partial \omega }(z,\omega) \right |\leq c$$
Show that $(z(t),\omega(t))$ is finite solution $\forall t\in \mathbb{R}$ using Gronwall's inequality.Which is :

$p,q,r :I \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \quad p,q\in C(I) , \quad I=[t_0, \infty),[t_0,T],[t_0,T)$ and $r^-$ can be integrated.

If $q \geq 0$ and $$p(t)\leq r(t)+\int^{t}_{t_0}q(s)p(s)ds \quad \forall t\in I \quad :(2)$$

then

$$p(t)\leq r(t)+\int^{t}_{t_0}r(s)q(s)e^{\int^{t}_{s}q(\phi)d\phi}ds \quad \forall t\in I \quad:(3)$$
If $r \uparrow$ then $$p(t)\leq r(t) \cdot e^{\int^{t}_{t_0}q(s)ds}\quad :(4)$$
My Solution:
$$(1)\Rightarrow -\int^{t}_{0}c(|\omega|+1)ds\leq \int^{t}_{0}-c\sqrt{|\omega|^2 +1}ds\leq \int^{t}_{0}\frac{d \omega}{dt}dt \leq \int^{t}_{0}c\sqrt{|\omega|^2 +1}ds \leq \int^{t}_{0}c\sqrt{(|\omega|+1)^2}ds=\int^{t}_{0}c(|\omega|+1)ds$$ $$\Rightarrow -c\int^{t}_{0}(|\omega|+1)ds \leq \omega(t)-b \leq \int^{t}_{0}c(|\omega|+1)ds \quad :(5)$$

If $b>0$ :
$$-b-\int^{t}_{0}c(|\omega|+1)ds\leq b-\int^{t}_{0}c(|\omega|+1)ds\leq \omega(t)\leq b +\int^{t}_{0}c(|\omega|+1)ds$$  $$\Rightarrow |\omega(t)|\leq b+ct+\int^{t}_{0}c|\omega(s)|ds \quad :(6)$$
$(6)$ looks like $(2)$ therefore from $(3)$ we have :
$$\Rightarrow |\omega(t)|\leq b +ct +\int^{t}_{0} (b+sc)c e^{\int^{t}_{s}cd\phi}ds$$
$$\Rightarrow |\omega(t)|\leq b+ct +\int^{t}_{0}bce^{ct}e^{-cs}ds+\int^{t}_{0}c\cdot s\cdot ce^{ct}e^{-cs}ds$$
$$\Rightarrow |\omega(t)|\leq b+ct-b +be^{ct}-ct-1+e^{ct}$$
$$\Rightarrow |\omega(t)|\leq (b+1)e^{ct}-1$$
How can I show that $|\omega(t)|$ is finite ?

Comment: There is a minus sign missing in the Hamiltonian system. // Does "finite" mean "finite values at finite times"? Or is the claim that the solutions are bounded over all the time?

Comment: I'm not sure in what form you discussed the Grönwall lemma and other bounding theorems. Here the integration can be carried out directly. $|w'|\le c\sqrt{1+w^2}$ can be simplified via $w=\sinh(u)$ so that $|u'|\le c$, which integrates to $|u(t)-u_0|\le c|t-t_0|$. The other equation says directly $|z'|\le c$, so that $|z(t)-z_0|\le c|t-t_0|$. All this only gives bounded values on bounded intervals. Take the pendulum equation as example, if the energy is high enough the motion is a rotation, the angle continuously increasing.

Comment: Finally I have to prove that the solution is finite $\forall t \in \mathbb{R}$.Any help?

Comment: Are you missing a minus sign in the equation? That system is not Hamiltonian

Comment: yes it is missing,you are right,

Answer (score 1):

You can solve quite directly the differential inequalities that follow from your assumptions on the derivatives of $H$.
For the first one, you get the inequality
$$
|w'|≤c\sqrt{1+w^2}.
$$
This can be simplified via a parametrization as $w=\sinh(u)$, where $u$ is likewise smoothly dependent on $w$. Inserting and applying the chain rule, then cancelling the always positive factor $\cosh(u)$ results in
$$
 |u'|≤c\implies |u(t)−u_0|≤c|t−t_0|.
$$
The other equation says directly
$$
|z'|≤c\implies |z(t)−z_0|≤c|t−t_0|. 
$$
This means that the solution has a linear bound at all points of its domain.  As therefore a divergence in finite time is impossible, any solution actually exists at all times and is thus finite at all times $t\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: I understand your solution but I have to use the eq.(3) or eq.(4) (Grownwall's inequality), how can i do this ?

Comment: Could i use the same argument  with you that |w(t)|  is bounded by (b+1)e^ct-1so the solution has a bound at all points of its domain as therefore  a divergence in finite time is impossible?I am waiting for your answer .Thank you. @LutzLehmann

Comment: Yes, you can do also that, the upper bound is then slightly larger, but can be used the same for the claim.